# Report from ADO for test results having attachment

Tags: attachment, ado, test-results

Is it possible to get a report from ADO to tell which test cases have attachments as part of test results as an evidence of test success? Please note that I am not talking about attachments when test cases are defined.

I have not tried anything as right now I want to know whether it is feasible.